# How to use Java code to save facebook into html file?

Tags: java, html, facebook, authentication

My works is save one facebook address into *.html file using javacode.

Ex: www.facebook.com/hiriji.sakumo.

You can easily save that page using web browser.

But in Java code, the problem is facebook demand log in account to see that site.
So i want to ask how to use java code to log in facebook and save page to htm file.

Thank you.

Comment: I, personally, would use [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)

Comment: Could you post what you've done so far?